# Curl command not working (Spring Boot project)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, curl

I want to display all messages from MySQL database that start with id = 275. I wrote a curl request I don’t know. Maybe the request was written incorrectly. Maybe the query syntax made a mistake -

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"messageId\": \"275\" }" localhost:8080/api/unread
```

But when I run this curl request through the command line, it shows an error.

```
{"timestamp":"2020-01-06T03:13:07.899+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(
```

My code
Input Message class

```
public class InputMessage {

    private long messageId;

    public InputMessage(long messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public InputMessage() {
    }

    public long getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(long messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }
}
```

RestController

```
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    TimerTask timerTask;

    @Resource
    private final MessageService messageService;

    public RestController(MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/save")
    public MessageStatus saveMessage(@RequestBody Message chatMessage) {
        return messageService.add(chatMessage);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/last")
    public String getLasts() {
        return new Gson().toJson(messageService.getLast());
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/unread")
    public void getUnreadMessages() {

        timerTask.run();
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/unread/byid")
    public List<Message> getUnreadById(@RequestBody InputMessage message) {
        return messageService.getUnreadById(message);
    }
```

Message Service Impl

```
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    private final MessageRepository repository;
    private final PageRequest lastRequest;

    private List<Long> chekedMessages = new ArrayList<>();


    @Autowired
    public MessageServiceImpl(MessageRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        lastRequest = new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
    }

    @Override
    public MessageStatus add(@RequestBody  Message message) {
        if(message == null) {
            System.out.println("Пришел пустой запрос на сохранение данных");

        }
        MessageStatus status = new MessageStatus();
        try {
            repository.save(message);
            status.setMessage("Сообщение успешно сохранено");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            status.setMessage("Во время сохранения сообщения произошла ошибка");
        }
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> getLast() {
        List<Message> result = repository.findAll(lastRequest).getContent();

        return result.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Message::getId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> getUnreadById(InputMessage message) {
         return repository.getUnreadById(message.getMessageId());
    }



    @Override
    public String getUnreadMessages() {
        List<Message> out = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Message> unchekedMessages = repository.findAll();
        for (Message message: unchekedMessages) {
            if (!chekedMessages.contains(message.getId())) {
                chekedMessages.add(message.getId());
                out.add(message);
            }
        }
        return new Gson().toJson(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMessage(long id, Message message) {
        if (repository.findById(id).isPresent()) {
            message.setId(id);
            repository.save(message);
        }
    }
```

github 
https://github.com/fallen3019/vaadin-chat

Comment: Note that the HTTP verb _already_ contains information about "save" and so on; the usual REST path to create an object is just `POST /objects`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your controller and curl request, you are calling `/api/unread` which is declared as `GET` request in your `RestController#getUnreadMessages()`.

Guessing you meant to hit POST `/api/save`, in that case simply change the curl request to following
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"messageId\": \"275\" }" localhost:8080/api/save`

If you meant to call `/api/unread`, as this is GET request that doesn't require any params, you can simply call it as 
`curl -X GET "localhost:8080/api/unread" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"messageId\": \"275\" }" localhost:8080/api/unread  rigth?

Comment: `curl -X GET "localhost:8080/api/unread" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`
that's all!

Comment: You misunderstood me, I need to show all messages that start with id = 275

Comment: @bella0304 that was not your question. Your question was why the code you presented returns a `405` error message. [Please ask only one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: @bella0304 Well, in that case, you need to modify your API itself. Going by best REST API design practices, you can take `messageId` as path param in the API URL itself. As in `api/unread/{messageId}`. Then in your controller, you read `messageId` as `@PathVariable Long messageId`. Based on this messageId, you do service call and return result

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear it thinks you execute a post call not a get call. Please specify `-X GET` and keep the data in -d as you already do.
I'm pretty sure curl assumes -X with -d is POST by default if no otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0):

As per the program code presented, the endpoint `/api/unread` does only support `GET`, not `POST`. To set off a `GET` via curl, add `-X GET`:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    # -d "{ \"messageId\": \"275\" }" \ # as of now, the body is not used and can be commented-out
    -X GET \ 
    -v \ # enable debug output to see response headers
    localhost:8080/api/unread
```

Or, alternatively, change the endpooint to `/api/save`:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "{ \"messageId\": \"275\" }" \
    localhost:8080/api/save
```

Comment: Api save, for him I have another curl request

Comment: I wrote the `GET`-example first since this example introduces something "new" (`-X GET`) =)

Comment: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"messageId\": \"275\" }" -X GET localhost:8080/api/unread   rigth?

Comment: The corresponding endpoint is a `void` method (`public void getUnreadMessages()`). If `timerTask.run()` starts an asynchronous task or returns (in a timely manner), you should see a `200 OK` response header and an empty body. Make sure to add `-v` to the `curl` command to see the response headers. Also, you cann remove the body (`-d { ... }`) from the `curl` command since it is not evaluated by the endpoint.

Comment: [You lack the reputation to write in chat.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)

Comment: I will not provide you my mobile number. sorry.

Comment: If you have a further question, please create a new post.